# Using Graph API to manage Microsoft Intune

Tags: powershell, graph, scope, roles, intune

I am trying to manange Roles and Scope for Microsoft Intune using Powershell and Graph

Graph API https://graph.microsoft.com/Beta/deviceManagement/roleScopeTags allows to read or create ScopeTags. But I don't find any way to assign group as it is possible on Microsoft Intune portal ? Is is possible throw Graph ?

Is there a Grah API available (or other method) to assign a Build-In Intune Roles (for example 'Help Desk Operator') to an Admin group, Scope Group, Scope Tags), as it is possible throw Microsoft Intune Portal ?

Regards
Gilles

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using the built-in cmdlets and or the modules from the MS powershellgallery.com?

```
Find-Module -Name '*graphapi*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

<#
Version Name              Repository Description                                                      
------- ----              ---------- -----------                                                      
0.4.0   MicrosoftGraphAPI PSGallery  Module for accessing Microsoft Graph API                         
0.4     MSGraphAPI        PSGallery  PowerShell cmdlets for the Microsoft Graph API. Currently in beta
1.0.5   Office365GraphAPI PSGallery  Office 365 Graph API Module(Both support WW AND Gallatin).\AzureResourcesReportbyTags.ps1
#>
```

> [Microsoft.Graph.Intune 6.1902.1.10](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Intune/6.1902.1.10) PowerShell SDK for Microsoft
>   Intune Graph API
>
> [MSGraphIntuneManagement 0.2](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSGraphIntuneManagement/0.2)
>
> PowerShell module for working with the Microsoft Graph Intune API.
>   This module is meant to bridge the gap and be a starting point for
>   those who want to use PowerShell to administer the Intune service
>   until an official Intune PowerShell module is provided by Microsoft.
>
> [Microsoft Intune PowerShell Module](https://techwizard.cloud/2019/07/03/microsoft-intune-powershell-module)
>
> [microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/tree/master/RBAC)
>
> RBAC_Add.ps1  RBAC samples update 2 years ago
>
> RBAC_Add_Assign.ps1   RBAC samples update 2 years ago
>
> RBAC_DuplicateRole.ps1    Update duplicateRole to specify new
>   displayName   14 months ago
>
> RBAC_Export.ps1   APNS and RBAC Export Import addition    2 years ago
>
> RBAC_Get.ps1  APNS and RBAC Export Import addition    2 years ago
>
> RBAC_Import_FromJSON.ps1  APNS and RBAC Export Import addition    2 years
>   ago
>
> RBAC_Remove.ps1   RBAC samples update 2 years ago
>
> RBAC_ScopeTags_ApplicationAssign.ps1  Added scope Tag sample for
>   Applications  13 months ago
>
> RBAC_ScopeTags_ApplicationUnAssign.ps1    Added scope Tag sample for
>   Applications  13 months ago
>
> RBAC_ScopeTags_DeviceAssign.ps1   Batch and Device Scope Tag addition 13
>   months ago
>
> RBAC_ScopeTags_DeviceUnAssign.ps1 Batch and Device Scope Tag
>   addition  13 months ago
>
> RBAC_ScopeTags_PolicyAssign.ps1   Update to ScopeTag Policy assign
>   functions 13 months ago
>
> RBAC_ScopeTags_PolicyUnAssign.ps1 Update to ScopeTag Policy assign
>   functions 13 months ago
>
> RBAC_UserStatus.ps1   RBAC samples update 2 years ago
>
> Readme.md Added scope Tag sample for Applications 13 months ago

Comment: Thanks you for your response, but I have already analyze all informations speak on, and they don't respond to by request. For example function "Get-RBACScopeTag" return information on Scope Tag (name and description) but does not return group associated as the portal does. That's why I ask some help

Comment: Also in the commands below, I don't find the command to create a Intune role as you can do on the Portal. Do you know how to do ?